# Run spinnaker pipeline only if new tag found

Tags: continuous-deployment, spinnaker

We use spinnaker to deploy dockerized microservices over all environments. Process description:

1. Integration env - pipeline is triggered by new tag appears in registry
2. QA env - manually triggered int-to-qa pipeline:

   1. Step "Find Image from Cluster" to find what tag is deployed on the Integration env
   2. Deploy found tag to QA env

This process works fine. But there is an enhancement I want to implement.

We have another pipeline to move all deployed services from Integration to QA env. It triggers int-to-qa pipeline for all service even for those where INT and QA versions are the same, and deploy is not required. So "Redeploy All" pipeline updates all 20 services, when only 6 of them require for update.

I want to change int-to-qa pipeline:

1. Find Image from Integration
2. Find Image from QA
3. If images 1 and 2 are the same - complete pipeline successfully
4. Otherwise, deploy Integration image to QA

And I don't have any idea how to implement step 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `check preconditions` stage with SPeL expressions to compare the images. This `check preconditions` stage would depend on both your "Find Image from Integration" Stage and your "Find Image from QA" Stage. In the `check preconditions` stage, add a check with type "expression", and use the [expression docs](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline-expressions/) to compare the images from the previous stages. In case you didn't know, you can view the stage json by clicking the 'source' link in the bottom right of the pipeline execution view, or by visiting `your-spinnaker-api-url/pipelines/your-execution-uuid`.